# how to read resource from module jar file

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, resources

In my multi module maven project ,learning_jaxrs (parent project)

[image]

commonapi module(packaging jar) contains resources in src/main/resources ,and i am reading files using my below util class

```
public class FileUtils {

private static final ClassLoader CLASS_LOADER = FileUtils.class.getClassLoader();

/**
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String readFileAsString(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String result = null;
    result = new String(readAllBytes(getFilePath(fileName)),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return result;
}

/**
 * It will return fully qualified path of resource file name
 *
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 */
public static Path getFilePath(String fileName) {
    Path result = null;
    URL resource = CLASS_LOADER.getResource(fileName);
    if (resource != null) {
        result = get(resource.getFile());
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

reading file

```
 String jsonTestData = readFileAsString("testEmployees.json");
```

when i ran local tests for commonapi module everything works fine .

But its not working when i deployed httpmethods module(war) on my server ,i am getting following exception ..

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /content/httpmethods-1.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/commonapi-1.0.jar/testEmployees.json
```

httpmethods war archive does contain commonapi jar in web-inf/lib and common api jar has file too

[image]
[image]

Edit :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

solved the problem

Comment: can you tell what file path you are requesting to readFileAsString() method.

Comment: sorry forgot to put that line ,just updated question.

Comment: thanks for linking to related question ,last answer from that question solved issue.